# Swift VSCode Class in other file not recognized

Tags: swift, linux, visual-studio-code

On a clean ubuntu 20.04 installation I installed the Swift compiler, Visual Studio Code, downloaded the sourcekit-lsp and installed the plugin I build from it into Visual Studio Code.

> Swift version 5.2.4 (swift-5.2.4-RELEASE) Target: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu

Everything seems to work as expected, except for classes that are in different files, which are not recognized within VSCode:

> use of unresolved identifier 'Calculator'

However, when building and running the application, everything is fine and works as expected.

[image]

Multiple people in the past seem to have had the same issue, but I have so far been unable to find any answer to how I might resolve the issue.

Comment: I also want to know the solution. I'm using vscode in mac for swift command line programs and want to create multiple class in different files.