# Swift command line program with multiple files in VSCode on Mac

Tags: swift, visual-studio-code, command-line-tool

I want to run a full fledged Swift command line program with multiple classes and multiple files, on Visual Studio Code. I'm using Macbook Air macOS Big Sur v11.2

I have setup VSCode from [this tutorial](https://nshipster.com/vscode/). I am able to run single file swift program but when I try to create new class in another file (in same directory/folder), it doesn't recognize. refer the screenshots:

[image: vscode screenshot]

**Consider, in Xcode similar to New project -> macOS -> command line tool**. there we can have multiple files and we can define multiple classes in different files and still inherit or create object of those classes in main.swift file.

I'm pretty sure it's possible in VSCode too. May be we just need to structure the code and have a configuration. that is what i am looking for.

just similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62214282/swift-vscode-class-in-other-file-not-recognized) but seems no experienced people bother to answer :/

ps- I'm new to swift and using VSCode. but instead of using xCode (12 GB of installation and 25 GB occupied storage just for few command line programs), I want to use VSCode.

Comment: Did you try to work with `swift build` and a `Package.swift`file

Comment: Previously I thought the same but don't know how to make `package.swift` file and use `swift build`. can you guide me or redirect me towards any specific link. It'd be much helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Just as a small hint, consider the following file structure:

```
./Package.swift
./src
./src/classA.swift
./src/main.swift
```

- In `src`, your source files reside
- `Package.swift` is the so-called *manifest* file (see below)

Then, you can build your project with

```
swift build
```

which will create the executable in `./.build/debug/testCli`

### **The manifest**

Here an example `Package.swift` file. You might also want to check the official [Package Description documentation](https://docs.swift.org/package-manager/PackageDescription/PackageDescription.html)

```
// swift-tools-version:5.1
import PackageDescription

let package = Package(name: "testPackage", products: [
    .executable(name: "testCli", targets: ["testCli"])
], targets: [
    .target(name: "testCli",
            path: "src"
    )
])
```

Comment: I'm getting error: `no such module 'PackageDescription'`. I looked into the error and found this link: https://forums.swift.org/t/no-such-module-packagedescription-sourcekitd/29406/2
unfortunately I'm unable to understand how to change the config

Comment: Strange, haven't seen this. You might wanna try something like this here: https://forums.swift.org/t/command-line-build-fails-with-mainfest-parse-error-no-such-module-packagedescription/35298/7

Comment: appreciate your help, but it seems that the link and setup that is been suggested are above my understanding level :/ I need to educate myself more towards swift builds and toolchains. and also seems like my vscode has broken setup. I'm frustrated..

Comment: I'm upvoting this answer as it helps, but still I'm unable to setup so keeping the thread open.